# angularJS service object property undefined

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller using a service `chartFactory.chartData` property to give some data to view. The problem is that the factory is returning the object before the `chartFactory.chartData` function has time to return the data from the back end, so the property is undefined.

I understand this is an async issue, but I'm not sure how to handle it between a factory and a controller.

chartFactory.js

```js
app.factory('chartFactory', ['$http', '$interval', function($http, $interval) {
  var service = {
    get chartData() {
      $http.get('/portfolio/get-chart-data')
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response.data, 'response data') //logging after undefined message
          return response.data
        })
    }
  }
  return service
}])
```

chartController.js

```js
app.controller('chartCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http, chartFactory) {
  $scope.chartData = chartFactory
      $scope.height_chart = window.innerHeight * 0.4
      $scope.labels = chartFactory.chartData[0]; //undefined
      $scope.series = chartFactory.chartData['GDAX Value']; //undefined
      $scope.data = [
        chartFactory.chartData[1] //undefined
      ];
      $scope.onClick = function(points, evt) {
        console.log(points, evt);
      };
      $scope.datasetOverride = [{
        yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
      }];

      $scope.options = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            //    type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: false,
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                  return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                } else {
                  return '$' + value;
                }
              }
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            display: false
          }]
        }
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller as,

```
chartFactory.chartData().then(function(response) {
  $scope.labels = getchartData .response.data[0];  
  $scope.series = chartFactory.response.data['GDAX Value'];  
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution, because now when switching between tabs in the one page app, the chart reloads every time. I would like a solution where the controller data is bound to factory data, and if the factory data changes the controller data changes without loading from scratch. does that make sense?

Comment: @chuckieDub check the answer